# How to set up credentials file in Google Colab python notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

**Goal**

I'd like to have a credentials file for things like API keys stored in a place where someone I've shared the Colab notebook with can't access the file or the information.

**Situation**

I'm calling several APIs in a Colab Notebook, and have multiple keys for different APIs. I'd prefer a simpler approach, if there are different levels of complexity.

**Current attempts**

I'm storing the keys in the main Python notebook, as I'm researching the best way to approach this. I'm pretty new at authentication, so would prefer a simpler solution. I haven't seen any articles addressing this directly.

Greatly appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save on Google Drive as follows:

1. Create `.env` file

   ```
   OPENAI_API_KEY="xxxxxx"
   ```
2. Mount Google Drive

   ```
   # from google.colab import drive    
   # drive.mount('/content/drive')
   ```
3. Load the key

   ```
   import dotenv
   import openai
   import os

   dotenv.load_dotenv('/content/drive/MyDrive/01 Work File/Credentials/.env')
   openai.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

   print(openai.api_key)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can store the credential files in your Google Drive.

Only you can access them at `/content/drive/MyDrive/` after mounting it. Other people need their own credential files in their own Drive.